# jQuery tabs and validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery tabs and validating all fields are filled in prior to allow the user to move to the next tab. On a few of the tabs there are options where the user can choose from multiple options and, sometimes, the user will click option 1 and mean option 2 but when they try and click the previous button this validates the fields and won't let them until they have filled in all the fields which is a rubbish UX.

I would like to only validate on clicking a next button but not on clicking a previous button.

```
<a class="btn nexttab navbutton" href="#step1">Previous</a>
<a class="btn nexttab navbutton" href="#step3">Next</a>
```

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
var validator = $("#start").validate();

var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var valid = true;
        var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
        var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");

        $(panelId).find(":input").each(function() {
            console.log(valid);
            if (!validator.element(this) && valid) {
                valid = false;
            }
        });

        return valid;
    }
});
```

To try and overcome this I added a class called next button to the next buttons only and then tried to change this line which I assume checks any input:

```
$(panelId).find(":input").each(function() {
```

to:

```
$(".nextbutton").click(function() {
```

but it allows the user to move to the next screen without having to fill in all the fields.

How can I make it so only forward movement is validated?

http://jsfiddle.net/553xmzh3/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to only validate on clicking a next button but not on clicking a previous button.  ....  How can I make it so only forward movement is validated?

Simply put a `cancel` class on your "previous" button.  All validation rules will automatically be ignored when a submit button contains a `cancel` class.  However, the `submitHandler` will fire as if the form is valid.

```
<input type="submit" value="PREVIOUS" class="cancel" /><!--// This submit will not trigger validation //-->

<input type="submit" value="NEXT" /><!--// This submit will trigger validation //-->
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4zdL8ha3/**

---

**EDIT:**

Although it still works, [using `class="cancel"` has been officially deprecated and replaced with formnovalidate="formnovalidate"](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-skipping-validation-on-submit)

```
<input type="submit" value="PREVIOUS" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4zdL8ha3/1/**

---

Since you're using anchor tags instead of `type="submit"` elements, this solution will not work for you.  It would be best to replace your anchor tags with a `button` element.  That way, using CSS, you can style the `button` to look exactly the same as an anchor.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn nexttab navbutton" formnovalidate="formnovalidate">Previous</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn nexttab navbutton">Next</button>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4zdL8ha3/2/**

---

**EDIT**:

If you must have anchor tags in place of `type="submit"` buttons, then you need to write the appropriate click handlers and check the form's validity only on the "next" button handlers.  Using the `.valid()` method also simplifies your code by **removing** your custom validation tester from the tab switcher function.

```
$(".nexttab").click(function () { // NEXT BUTTON
    if ($("#start").valid()) {    // TEST VALIDATION 
        $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
    }
});

$(".cancel").click(function () {  // PREVIOUS BUTTON - NO VALIDATION TEST
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
});
```

Initializations:

```
var validator = $("#start").validate();

var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var current = $(this).tabs("option", "selected");
        var panelId = $("#tabs ul a").eq(current).attr("href");
        return true;
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/553xmzh3/3/**

Comment: It doesn't appear to work for me - I read http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#skipping-validation-on-submit that using class=cancel is now deprecated. Also I am using a href for the previous/next as I am using this within tabs, might that make a difference?

Comment: @bhttoan, deprecated or not, it's working in the jsFiddle above.  The new way is also working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4zdL8ha3/1/   ~ The fact that you're using anchor tags instead of `type="submit"` elements has everything to do with your failure.  You should have shown that markup in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky - the problem with the anchor tags answer is I am using tabs so I need to assign an href to the link which was why I used anchor tags in the first place rather than actual buttons and I know of no valid way to include a link in a button without using onclick

Comment: @bhttoan, you need to write custom click handlers for the different types of buttons.  See my edited answer.